# Area Boundaries, London

Tags: shapefile, data, toponyms

Hope someone can help me with this. I'm having a little trouble finding a data set which has polygons of London districts as listed here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_districts

I've checked Ordnance Survey and none of their boundary data sets corresponds to the above list. I have Borough polygons & ward polygons but need the above as (based on my knowledge of a couple of boroughs) these equate to sub-borough areas people would commonly refer to in everyday life.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the polygons you were after do exist, they look like Local Authority Districts to me and they're available from the Office of National Statistics because they're census type datasets. Here's the link: https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/geoportal/catalog/content/filelist.page.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is available with the **Ordnance Survey Opendata Boundary Line** dataset.

https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html
see BoundaryLine (Download as Shapefile)

**Note:** It is worth looking at the start guide for more information on this dataset.

OS OpenData getting started guide (page 12)
http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/docs/user-guides/os-opendata-getting-started-guides.pdf#page=12

Boundary-Line
Product description
Boundary-Line is a vector digital mapping product that is a complete set of local government administrative boundaries and electoral boundaries used in local and general election voting. It has been specifically designed to show the area of each administrative or electoral boundary.
The product contains the following boundaries:
•
Civil parishes and communities.
•
**Counties, Districts, Wards, Metropolitan districts, Electoral divisions.**
•
Greater London Authorities and Assembly, London boroughs, Metropolitan districts, Unitary authorities.
•
Westminster parliamentary constituencies, Scottish parliamentary constituency and Electoral region,
Welsh Assembly constituency and Electoral region.
•
European electoral region.
Mean high water mark and Census agency codes.
Scale
Print: 1:10 000 scale recommended
Screen: 1:5000 – 1:8000
Coordinates
National Grid
Coverage
Great Britain (England, Scotland and Wales)

Comment: Don't be discerned with the name Boundary**Line** it was linework back in when the only format OS would output was NTF (National_Transfer_Format) in 1988. Spent many hours converting to polygon shapefiles.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I have downloaded. Unfortunately none of the boundary data sets have polygons of commonly referred to sub-borough areas. I'm wondering if the list above (from wiki) exists in any official shapefile release.

Comment: If you actually click on the image on your wiki link page it tells you where the mapping data was sourced from, which as mapperz rightfully spotted was OS opendata

Comment: The map data was sourced from OS but the map doesn't show polygons of the areas listed, just a generalized map of London. So still don't know whether there is a shapefile with polygons of the places listed. I'm not sure if I've misunderstood the content of what Mapperz / you wrote. Thanks Hornbydd and Mapperz for your help so far -

Answer (score 0):

If you are an academic/student you can download this boundary data from [edina](http://edina.ac.uk/).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the london district list (as shown in the link) is not in any of the Edina / OS Open Data datasets. The closest it gets to is the District Borough Unitary Ward Region set, but it's not quite like the one above and has a fair few area names that would not normally be used. I don't know if the above list exists in any official capacity, and if it does, what it is actually called.

Comment: By not normally be used I mean they're not commonly used as place names (to refer to sub-borough areas).